# OAuthWebSecurity FacebookClient: How can I add additional permissions to the scope request?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, facebook-oauth

In my AuthConfig.cs I've enabled the out of the box Facebook Client but when the app authorization request goes out, it only passes scope=email and I need to include the manage_pages permission. How can force the request to include the manage_pages permission?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the AuthConfig provided with MVC project template it will use **FacebookClient** from **DotNetOpenAuth** (4.1.0.0). It cannot do what you want it to do.

The scope is hardcoded to only inculde email.

You could use **FacebookClient** from **DotNetOpenAuth** (4.3.0.0). This one allows for providing the scope.

Comment: Mikeon: How do you provide teh scope with RequestAuthentication in 4.3.0.0? I can't see an overload that permits it?